# Display the category name of a post that is in two different categories

Tags: categories

I'm trying to get the category of a post that is in 2 different category.
One category is always "Featured" and the other changes.

I can only see the word `Array()`

This is my code:

```
<?php $args = array( 'numberposts' => '1', 'order' => 'DESC','category' => 17 );
   $recent_posts = wp_get_recent_posts( $args );
//Now lets do something with these posts
foreach( $recent_posts as $recent )
    {
        echo '<div id="testata">';
        echo '<a href="' . get_permalink($recent["ID"]) . '" title="Dettaglio '.esc_attr($recent["post_title"]).'" >'  ;
        echo get_the_post_thumbnail($recent["ID"],"thumb-category") ;
        echo '</a>';
        echo '<div class="testata_inner">';
        echo '<span class="'.get_the_category($recent["cat_name"]) . '">';
        if ($cat[0]->name != "Featured") {
            echo $cat[0]->name;
        } else {
            echo $cat[1]->name;
        }
        echo '</span>';
        echo '<p>'.esc_attr($recent["post_title"]).'</p>';
        echo '<span class="' . esc_attr($recent["post_author"]) . '">' . esc_attr($recent["post_author"]) . '</span>';
        echo '</div> ';
        echo '</div> ';

    } ?>
```

Comment: `$cat` isn't defined. You can't `echo` an array or you will just get "Array". Try `var_dump($your_variable_name)` and you should see the structure of your data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should get you going in the right direction.

```php
echo '<div class="testata_inner">';
$cat = get_the_category($recent["ID"]); //get the category array
if ($cat[0]->name != "Featured") { //check if the category is "featured"
    $catname = $cat[0]->name; //set $catname variable to "featured"
} else {
    $catname = $cat[1]->name; //or set $catname variable to "other category name"
}
echo '<span class="'. $catname . '">';
echo $catname; //output $catname variable
echo '</span>';
```